# Changing dualboot menu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

Yesterday, I removed my wubi-installed Ubuntu and installed it from CD on a separate partition. Before, when I started my computer, a "BIOS-styled" menu popped up where I could choose between Windows and Ubuntu (in this order). However, after installing Ubuntu like described, this menu is now "Ubuntu-like", where Ubuntu is the first choice, then some other points which I do not exactly understand, and at last, two times "Windows 7". My  questions now are:

- How can I set Windows to start as default?
- How can I make this choosing menu in "BIOS-style"? Meaning that there is only "Windows" and "Ubuntu" as choice.

Comment: that was a spelling fix, I corrected it

Comment: I had trouble with formatting. Additionally, I please that If somebody downvotes my question, at least tell me the reason in order to evaluate the posting of future questions. Since my english is not my first language, I sometimes have troubles finding the right words. In this case however, the purpose of my question should be very clear.

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather, you want to use the windows bootloader and not Grub that came as a part of installing Ubuntu.

If you want to edit these settings you could try using this tool: [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)
(Through your windows installation)

I think that might to the trick for you.

There are also alot of stuff on google describing "How to recover windows bootloader". 
Have a look and good luck! :)